# changing privacy settings of video using vimeo api

Tags: api, vimeo

i am trying to change the privacy settings of vimeo video using api class

below is my code

```
$vimeo = new phpVimeo('myconsumer_key', 'myconsumer_secret');


$info = $vimeo->call('vimeo.videos.setPrivacy', array('video_id' =>$videoid,'privacy'=>'nobody','users'=>$username,'password'=>""));
```

i provided the consumer key and consumer secret key which i generated from `https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new`  but when i call the function  error occoured

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'VimeoAPIException' with message 'Permission Denied' in D:\phpweb\Rohith\vimeo_video\vimeo.php:239 Stack trace: #0 D:\phpweb\Rohith\vimeo_video\vimeo.php(275): phpVimeo->_request('vimeo.videos.se...', Array, 'GET', 'http://vimeo.co...', true) #1 D:\phpweb\Rohith\vimeo_video\disablevideo.php(18): phpVimeo->call('vimeo.videos.se...', Array) #2 {main} thrown in D:\phpweb\Rohith\vimeo_video\vimeo.php on line 239
```

Comment: Access token is missing.